# How to get value of button on button click in node js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, forms

I am working on a form in React which POST the value of the button when clicked. But I am not able to find any solution to this, how I can get that value at the current URL and access it at the backend.
Here is my code from the react js file :

```
              <form action='http://localhost:5000/api/button' method='POST'>
              <button value = "firstButton"  type = "submit" className='btn' name = "clickBtn" onClick={handleClick()}>Click It</button>
              

              <button value = "secondButton"  type = "submit" className='btn' name = "clickBtn" onClick={handleClick()}>Click It</button>

              
              <button value = "thirdButton"  type = "submit" className='btn' name = "clickBtn" onClick={handleClick()}>Click It</button>
              </form>
```

Here is the code from my node js file :

```
const value = req.body;
console.log("Button clicked has value: " value.value)
```

Comment: Hello, can you share with us what `req.body` shows ?  i guess you should point it with `value.name`  **not** `value.value`

Comment: it shows undefined when I console value.value

Comment: yes it's normal because you are pointing on a property ".value" which does not exist, when you submit a form , you have to point on the property "name" of the request body made from the form (in your case the name should be (clickBtn), so the `req.body`should have a property `clickBtn` with the value `firstButton` or `secondButton` or `thirdButton` depending on which button was clicked , so you have to point it like `let value = req.body.clickBtn` and you have to be sure that you implemented `express.urlencoded({extended: true})` middleware in the server side too

Answer (score 0):

`req.body` isn't populated until you tell the app to use a parser.

Use this middleware to parse your incoming request body as a `urlencoded` string

```
app.use(
    express.urlencoded({
      extended: true
    })
)
```